# office outlook(web) display message details

Tags: fabricjs, outlook-addin, office-js

Iam developing my first office outlook web Add-in . Iam using VisualStudio2017 and Office2016 . What iam trying to achieve whenever you click on email in outlook it display the email data like sender name,email ,receipent name,email and full email message .I should have then possibility to download the full email file as .eml file. I have updated the AddInManifest file with 
    
with the following
`

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="messageDetailsService">
                      <Label resid="messageDetailsLabel"/>
                      <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="messageDetailsTitle"/>
                          <Description resid="messageDetailsDesc"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                             <SourceLocation resid="sendMessage"/>
                      </Action>
                  </Control>`
also update <bt:Url> to point to "SendMessage" html page . 

<bt:Url id="sendMsgToService" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/SendMessageService.html"/>
```

Javascript code:

```
    (function () {
        "use strict";
     Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                app.initialize();

                displayItemDetails();
            });
        };

       function displayItemDetails() {
                var item = Office.cast.item.toItemRead(Office.context.mailbox.item);
                $('#subject').text(item.subject);

                var from;
                if (item.itemType === Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message) {
                    from = Office.cast.item.toMessageRead(item).from;
                } else if (item.itemType === Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Appointment) {
                    from = Office.cast.item.toAppointmentRead(item).organizer;
                }

                if (from) {
                    $('#from').text(from.displayName);
                    $('#from').click(function () {
           app.showNotification(from.displayName, from.emailAddress);
                    });
                }
            }
        })();

HTML:
<div id="content-main">
    <div class="padding">
        <p><strong>Add home screen content here.</strong></p>
        <p>For example, this app was activated with following details:</p>
        <table id="details">
            <tr>
                <th>Subject:</th>
                <td id="subject"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>From:</th>
                <td id="from"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

After running the project iam able to see the AddIn and when i click on it opens the TaskPane but iam not getting any values of email message. Please tell what iam doin wrong here but strange thing is same code working VS2015 but not in VS2017

Comment: I tried your code, it seems to be working. I would suggest trying it on the outlook web app (office365.com or outlook.office.com) and seeing if you get any js console errors

Comment: its working in chrome but not in internet explorer

Comment: can i ask u where did u put javascript file ?

Comment: i get error in console SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Comment: I was also not able to repro. Grabbing item.subject works in both win32 Outlook, and OWA for IE. 

If you have a very simple add-in that can repro this consistently on a browser, we may be able to investigate further. It may be your IE settings are incompatible. Make sure you have IE 11 and Enable Protected Mode is on. If you have your Outlook Desktop Version, OWA versions and browser versions that could be helpful.

Comment: I tired a lot but nothing works soo I updated my window and its working on edge for both web and desktop version